# Audio crashes when backgrounding app / double tapping home button

Tags: ios, ios5, avfoundation, avplayer

I have an app that plays audio using AVPlayer.  I have enabled background audio by setting the audio category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and added the required `UIBackgroundModes` setting to `audio` in the info.plist.

On iOS 5, when you press the home button, the app goes in the background and audio still plays for a bit, but when I double tap the home button the whole device locks up for 10 seconds or so and the audio eventually stops.

The application is still running, however, because I can launch it and see the app's state just like it was.  Unfortunately the audio system seems to be borked, because any subsequent operation usually causes a crash.

When the audio stops, I see the following in the device's console:

```
Jun 26 12:39:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Unable to deliver SBApplicationNotificationStateChanged notification to port com.apple.springboard.appstatechanged: (ipc/send) timed out
Jun 26 12:39:53 unknown mediaserverd[25406] <Error>: <<<< FIGSERVER >>>> FigPlayerRemoteServer_KillAndForceCrashReport: RPCTimeout message received to terminate [25406] with reason 'fig rpc timeout -- FigSharedRemote_VolumeCategoryForAudioCategory'
Jun 26 12:39:53 unknown ReportCrash[25468] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/mediaserverd-2012-06-26-123953.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Jun 26 12:39:53 unknown mediaserverd[25406] <Error>: <<<< FIGSERVER >>>> FigPlayerRemoteServer_KillAndForceCrashReport: RPCTimeout message received; stackshot generated
Jun 26 12:39:53 unknown mediaserverd[25406] <Error>: <<<< FIGSERVER >>>> FigPlayerRemoteServer_KillAndForceCrashReport: TERMINATING our process [25406]
Jun 26 12:39:53 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.mediaserverd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun 26 12:39:54 unknown com.apple.mediaserverd[25469] <Notice>: 2012-06-26 12:39:54.083477 PM [AirTunes] HAL plugin started
Jun 26 12:39:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[25469] Builtin profile: mediaserverd (sandbox)
Jun 26 12:39:54 unknown mediaserverd[25469] <Error>: 12:39:54.317795 com.apple.AVConference: /SourceCache/GameKitServices/GameKitServices-344.21/AVConference.subproj/Sources/AVConferenceServer.m:1867: AVConferenceServerStart
```

This seems to only affect iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue in my code by sharing more than one `AVPlayer` instance, which caused the audio system to crash at times.  Removing the 2nd player fixed this bug.  */sigh*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, altough I simply had to use 2 AVPlayers because I had to do a crossfade.
After monitoring the allocations in Instruments it turned out AVPlayers not getting released properly (they remained "Living"). 
I was releasing them improperly. After I fixed that and they got released properly the problem was gone.